# Angular 2 - download csv file

Tags: angular, csv, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to download a csv file from a Microsoft Web API 2 controller. Here's what I have so far:-

Web API:-

```
    [Route("extractContent/{extractId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExtractContent(int extractId)
    {
        _logger.Info($"Getting extract file content for extract with id: {extractId}...");

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<ExtractDto> extracts = await _extractService.GetExtractsAsync(new ExtractSearchRequest { ExtractId = extractId });

            ExtractDto extract = extracts?.FirstOrDefault();

            if (extract != null)
            {
                string path = extract.FilePath;

                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                using (result.Content = new StreamContent(stream))
                {
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(path)
                    };
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                    return Ok(result);
                }
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find extract with id: {extractId}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException($"An error occured trying to get extract content for extract with id: {extractId}", e);

            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

Angular 2 Download Service:-

```
@Injectable()
export class DownloadService {
private baseAddress: string;
private headers: Headers;
private options: RequestOptions;

constructor(private http: Http, private config: Config, private errorService: ErrorService) {
    this.baseAddress = config.cache.get('portfolioUploadApiUrl');
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true, responseType:  ResponseContentType.Blob});
}

getExtractContent(extractId: number): Observable<Blob> {
   
    return this.http.get(this.baseAddress + 'extractContent/' + extractId, this.options)
        .map((response: Response) => 
            {
                return new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'application/csv'});
            }
        )
        .catch(this.errorService.handleError);
}
```

}

Angular 2 client code:-

```
onDownload(): void {
    if (this.extract && this.extract.FilePath) {
        this.downloadService.getExtractContent(this.extractId).subscribe(blob => {
            var date = new Date();
            var day = date.getDay();
            var month = date.getMonth();
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var seconds = date.getSeconds();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var formattedDate = day + '' + (month + 1) + '' + year + '' + hours + '' + minutes + '' + seconds;
            var fileName = "Extract" + this.extractId + "-" + formattedDate + ".csv";
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName)
        })
    }
}
```

However, when I run the download, I get a csv file downloaded which has the following in it:-

```
{"Version":{"_Major":1  _Minor:1    _Build:-1   _Revision:-1}   Content:{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Disposition"    Value:["attachment; filename=\"RPModel_Portfolio_ISY - 20170925.csv\""]}    {"Key":"Content-Type"   Value:["application/octet-stream"]}]}   StatusCode:200  ReasonPhrase:"OK"   Headers:[]  RequestMessage:null IsSuccessStatusCode:true}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get around this so I went with just providing a json representation of my csv data from my Web API action and then just using Angular2Csv Angular 2 library to convert this json object into a CSV file

For some reason, using ResponseMessage(result) rather than one of the other Web API wrappers (such as Ok(result)) means that CORS gets ignored for the actual request. The OPTIONS (pre-flight) request seems to work but the GET doesn't when using ResponseMessage(result) but it does when using Ok(result) so I can only assume that Ok(result) is doing something to use the Cors functionality provided in Web API 2

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem downloading a XML file from WebAPI.

There's a difference in RequestOptions, when have a Binary File (.PDF, .ZIP, ...) you can call as:

```
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true, responseType:  ResponseContentType.Blob});
```

But, when a file is Text File (.txt, .csv, ...) you have to call the API asking for a text file, so:

```
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true, responseType:  ResponseContentType.Text});
```

In my case, i create a procedure to receive the response from API and create the correspondent file.

```
saveFile(data, fileName: string, extentionFile: string) {
    var mediaType = data.headers.get("Content-Type");
    var file;

    if (extentionFile == "csv") {
        file = new Blob([data._body], { type: mediaType })
    } else {
        file = new Blob([data.blob()], { type: mediaType })
    }

    FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
}
```

When the Response returns a text, you create a blob from body of the Response. If returns a Binary file, you can call ".blob()".

I hope it helped you.

Comment: I changed my code to match yours but its still giving me the same output in the csv file

getExtractContent(extractId: number): Observable<Blob> {
       
        return this.http.get(this.baseAddress + 'extractContent/' + extractId, this.options)
            .map((data: any) => 
                {
                    var mediaType = data.headers.get("Content-Type");
                    var body = data._body;
                    return new Blob([body], {type: mediaType});
                }
            )
            .catch(this.errorService.handleError);
    }

Comment: And I also changed the options to:-

this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true, responseType:  ResponseContentType.Text});

but this made no difference.

I'm wondering if its because I'm doing this in the WebAPI action:-

Ok(result)

Comment: So I changed my web api action to return a ResponseMessage(result) but now I'm getting a 500 internal server error on the GET with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access". Dreaded CORS error. The OPTIONS pre-flight request responds with a 200 but then the GET responds with a 500 and the above error message. Any ideas?

Comment: The CORS have to disable in WEB API. You can do that in Startup.cs file (in your project).

Inside the method "Configuration", add:

HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors();

Comment: If the error in WebAPI, make a ResponseMessage and just returns a octstream (or application/csv). And watch's what is returned.

Test with POSTMAN, and see if the file can be downloaded there.

Comment: Any progress in this problem?

Comment: See my answer below