# How can I download or save a .csv file in browser in Angular Front End Web App on click of a link? browser complaints no file

Tags: javascript, angular, html, csv

The file is already at the front end of Angular Front End of Web App, I want the app user to be able to click a link and download or save the user-type.csv from /src/assets/user-type.csv in user's browser.

I have written below code, which is not working properly, Google Chrome tries to download but fails with no file. See the screenshot attached. I am running Angular 7 project on development server using 'ng serve' on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 operating system.

The anchor tag 'a' has download attribute, despite angular tries to navigate to the value of href and app crashes with following error:

Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'src/assets/user-type.csv'
Error: Cannot match any routes.

```
<a href="src/assets/user-type.csv" target="_blank" download>Download user-type.csv </a>
```

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8g77.png)

There are following answers available, but no one serves my purpose:

[Angular 2 - download csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412012/angular-2-download-csv-file)

[Angular 2 CSV File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201996/angular-2-csv-file-download)

Comment: What doe you mean by _"from /src/assets/user-type.csv in user's browser"_?

Comment: I guess the problem is with your `href` attribute. Try changing it to `href="/src/assets/user-type.csv`.

Comment: Try adding forward slash to your path.

Comment: @CodeIt, I changed to  href="/src/assets/user-type.csv but didn't work.
I also tried another thing. I placed a my-image.png in /src/assets/my-image.png and change anchor to <a href="/src/assets/my-image.png" download>Download</a> but this also didn't download the image file

Comment: @guest271314, I expected the file to be already available on user's browser as an asset, and saved to user's browser as .csv file when user clicks download link.

Comment: @NavneetPrakash Have you tried setting the full path to the resource at `href` of `<a>` element?

Comment: @guest271314, It downloads successfully when value of href is an absolute path to a resource available on internet.

Example: <a href="https://www.t-mobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/apple/apple-iphone-x/space-gray/Apple-iPhoneX-SpaceGray-1-3x.jpg" target="_blank" download> Download image file </a>

Above example works.

Comment: @NavneetPrakash Not following what the issue is or what you are trying to achieve? Does the `href` value point to a valid URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Download url should be `assets/user-type.csv`

Try this:

```
<div>
    <a 
    href="assets/user-type.csv" 
    target="_blank" 
    download="sample-file.csv">
        Download Import File Template
    </a>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/download-link-to-download-a-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, by your example I realised the problem was in the patch I gave beginning from 'src' like href="src/assets/user-type.csv" which is incorrect. The correct path is: href="assets/user-type.csv"